# How do you check the stability of a kink solution?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, stability, solitons

I am reading a nice introductory note by Hugo Laurell (http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:935529/FULLTEXT01.pdf) but got confused on section 3.2.

He claims the stability of kink by expanding a Lagrangian around the vacuum solution $\phi_{min}$ with some **arbitrary function** of small oscillation $\psi$ and reduce the equations of motion to eigenfrequencies problem.
$$-\partial_x^2 \psi_n + U'' (\phi_{min})\psi_n = \omega_n^2 \psi_n .$$
He then end the argument by saying that as long as $\omega_n$ is real, the solution $\psi$ is real.

Now I'm not sure how this implies the stability of kink? Is $\psi$ or $\phi_{min}$ suppose to be a kink solution? If $\psi$ is a kink solution, then how does one justify the small oscillation assumed for $\psi$ to perform perturbation?